# Xamarin.iOS problema al abrir storyboards con xcode

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, xamarin.ios

estoy trabajando con un proyecto Xamarin.iOS con Visual studio 2019 para mac, pero los StoryBoards los hago y modifico desde Xcode porque Vs siempre me genero problemas.
Ahora el problema que tengo desde la ultima actualización de xcode es que después de abrir un Storyboard con xcode, este me genera automaticamente los controllers de estos storyboards duplicandolo en el proyecto.
Mi pregunta es, hay una opción en xcode que pueda desactivar para que deje de generarme los viewcontrollers automaticamente?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Asignaste un [controlador personalizado](https://i.imgur.com/FjGouJ9.gif)?

Comment: Si, todos los storyboard tienen su controlador en otro path, pero estan bien referenciados, funcionan bien, pero si quiero modificar por ej, el color de una view en el storyboard, cuando lo cierro me genera el viewcontroller en el mismo path del stroyboard, y me genera un conflicto con el que ya existe en otro path

Comment: En teoría, al tener un controlador especificado, no debería crear otro. Antes de cerrarlo verifica que sí está bien referenciado en la pestaña de propiedades.

Comment: de casualidad eso no ocurre en el autobuild??

Comment: En Xcode tienes habilitado el check de Inherit Module From Target? Lo encuentras en donde asignas la clase al viewController. Puedes intentar desactivándolo.